# How to implement max height & scrollbar with YUI Panel?

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm using the [YUI Panel](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Panel.html) element that is rendered via an AJAX call. Is there a way to set a maximum height and use a scrollbar whenever the content of the panel exceeds that height?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely! Here is an example with a Dialog with id dlg:

```
var dialog = new YAHOO.widget.Dialog("dlg", { fixedcenter : true....
```

So then set the bd css class to auto overflow:

```
#dlg .bd {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And then in your js put something like:

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(dialog.body, "height", "300px");
```

You'll probably need to add some styling to the ft class also, but that's up to you:

```
#dlg .ft {
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #CECECE;
}
```

Comment: You can also just set the height in the panel config: `new YAHOO.widget.Panel("win", { height: "400px" }`

Comment: @Gabe for sure, I actually had a specific condition to apply the height in my code (if some counter was greater than 10, then apply the height of 300px) -- did a quick cut and paste :)

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't care about a specific height, but just want to avoid it being larger than the window then the following code handles that.

```
myDialog.renderEvent.subscribe(function() {
    // Find .yui-panel .bd
    let dialogElement = $('.yui-panel .bd');
    // set the max-height to the 90% of the screen
    let windowHeight = $(window).height();
    dialogElement.css('max-height', windowHeight*0.9);
    // set overflow:auto
    dialogElement.css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```